# No init found. Try passing init= bootarg. ( linux fedora 14 - rackspace )

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora, init

I have a server on Rackspace. It was working just fine. But this morning I found that it wasn't working, after a hard reboot (suggested by a rackspace chat support guy).

I found that it was giving me the error:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.                                                                           
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.                                                                              
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

I was told by the chat support guy to go into rescue mode, and do a fsck
on the root partition ( fsck /dev/sda1 ) which I did, but it didn't return
any errors. I was told to do this until it found an error... never
got an error after doing it many times.

What do I need to do get this fixed? Is it a hard fix?

( ps. I am trying to find a server guy on freelancer.com to fix this, but
thought it might be worth trying to figure it out myself )

Comment: Do you have a good backup? If init is gone, your system could be pretty much trashed.  If you got into a rescue mode, were you able to access the filesystem?  Was your data still present?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are seeing damage of your root filesystem. Try starting with a rescue system and running fsck /dev/sda1 (or whatever the device name / partition number of your root filesystem would be) - this should fix eventual filesystem corruption and return your host to a bootable state.